# Sorting Vector Alphabetically by Index Value

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, alphabetical

I have a vector that I want to sort alphabetically. I have successfully been able to sort it by one indexes value alphabetically, but when I do it only changes the order of that index and not the entire vector. How can I get it to apply the order change to the entire vector?
This is my current code I am running:

```
std::sort (myvector[2].begin(), myvector[2].end(), compare);

bool icompare_char(char c1, char c2)
{
  return std::toupper(c1) < std::toupper(c2);
}

bool compare(std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2)
{
  if (s1.length() > s2.length())
    return true;
  if (s1.length() < s2.length())
    return false;
  return std::lexicographical_compare(s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                                      s2.begin(), s2.end(),
                                      icompare_char);
}
```

My general structure for this vector is vector[row][column] where:

```
| One | Two | Three |
|  1  |  2  |   3   |
|  b  |  a  |   c   |
```

For example if I had a vector:

```
myvector[0][0] = 'One' AND myvector[2][0]='b'
myvector[0][1] = 'Two' AND myvector[2][1]='a'
myvector[0][2] = 'Three' AND myvector[2][2]='c'

| One | Two | Three |
|  1  |  2  |   3   |
|  b  |  a  |   c   |
```

And I sort it I get:

```
myvector[0][0] = 'One' AND myvector[2][0]='a'
myvector[0][1] = 'Two' AND myvector[2][1]='b'
myvector[0][2] = 'Three' AND myvector[2][2]='c'

| One | Two | Three |
|  1  |  2  |   3   |
|  a  |  b  |   c   |
```

and not what I want:

```
myvector[0][0] = 'Two' AND myvector[2][0]='a'
myvector[0][1] = 'One' AND myvector[2][1]='b'
myvector[0][2] = 'Three' AND myvector[2][2]='c'

| Two | One | Three |
|  2  |  1  |   3   |
|  a  |  b  |   c   |
```

I looked around for a good approach but could not find anything that worked... I was thinking something like:

```
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), compare);
```

Then handle the sorting of the third index within my compare function so the whole vector would get edited... but when I passed my data I either only changed the order in the function and still did not change the top layer or got errors. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're leaving out `myvector[1][...]` in your what-I-have/what-I-want descriptions. Any reason for that?

Comment: If you want to sort by the 2nd index, then `[2]` should appear *inside* `compare`. This will sort rows, not columns like you have shown, so you should transpose your data.

Comment: @whozCraig: I just left out the 1 index in-order to make less for you guys to read. I just used the vector with indexes to describe the basic structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, merge the 3 data fields into a `struct` so that you can have just 1 vector and so sort it simply.

```
struct DataElement{
    std::string str;
    char theChar;
    int num;
    bool operator<(const DataElement& other)const{return theChar<other.theChar;}
};

std::vector<DataElement> myvector;

std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

Comment: I have not worked with structs before because I am pretty new to c++. The idea of that makes sense but after reading a bit would I reference things like myvector[0].str = "One" and myvector[0].theChar = "b" and myvector[0].num = 1? Then how would I be able to edit my sort by myvector.theChar for every index?

Comment: @DevonBernard pls see my edit to see if that is what you want. It will sort the entire list in order of ascending `theChar`. If you dont give a compare function, default is to use `<` operation.

Comment: @Kerthik T: Alright, I just implemented your code and I was successfully able to insert all of the values into the vector struct. But I get an extremely long error when I try to sort it.

Comment: @DevonBernard That doesnt help :( can you copy-paste it in something like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and link it here?

Comment: Alright I posted the error on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VTzTxHcc) Also thank you very much for all of the help!

Comment: @DevonBernard can you make the function `const`, as I have, and try again?

Comment: @Kerthik T: I added the const like you said and now everything appears to work correctly. Thank you very much for your help and the great idea of using structs to combine everything!